# Arduino starter kit servo is shaking

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, map

In the example of the arduino starter kit the point is to use a potenciometer to control a servo.

The code is

```
angle = map(potVal, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
```

The output in the serial

```
potVal: 1023, angle: 179
potVal: 1015, angle: 177
potVal: 1023, angle: 179
potVal: 1016, angle: 177
potVal: 1023, angle: 179
potVal: 1023, angle: 179
```

I noticed that the servo is shaking like trying to go passing over the 179, when it is suppose to use an angle max 180º (0-179)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the serial output above occur **without** changing the pot position?

Comment: Yes, when I reach the "top" 1023 it shakes and oscilates between close values. Could it be a mechanical problem?

Comment: No, I just included the Servo library. It is a basic example, where a pot controls the servo.

Comment: It seems the problem comes from the pot not the servo. Since 2 consecutive reads don't provide the same value, the servo will change its position of a few degrees and looks like it is vibrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this method the best (personal preference) for smoothing signals:

```
//In setup
int bufferedVal = analogRead(A0);
int unbufferedVal = analogRead(A0);
#define _TOLERANCE_ 5

//The loop
unbufferedVal = analogRead(A0);
if(abs(unbufferedVal - bufferedVal) >= _TOLERANCE_ ) {
  bufferedVal = unbufferedVal;
}
```

This finds the error using the `abs()` function (absolute value; makes sure it is positive).

Another thing you can do is round it to the tenth placeholder (i.e. 88 -> 90, 83 -> 80) so it always is a good number to work with:

```
int val = analogRead(A0);
val += 5;
val = val / 10;
val = val * 10;
```

The last two lines work because of the lack of precision that integers offer with decimals. If I divide 88 by 10, it doesn't output 8.8; it outputs 8 instead. We then multiply by ten again so it isn't 8 when it really should be 80. The only problem with this is it only rounds down. We can fix this by adding 5 (the halfway point between 10 and 0). That way, it goes: 88 to 93 to 9.3 to 9 to 90.

**NOTE:** I'm not sure if the compiler will notice the redundancy of the last two lines. If it acts weird, try using the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: I had to set the tolerance to 10, but it worked.

Comment: Rounding the one's digit is likely to sometimes make the problem quite a bit worse - if the average value is near the rounding threshold, then small noise variations can get substantially amplified +1/-1 can become +5/-5.

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is due to jittery pot readings, you may want to smooth the `potval` data sequence by code like the following, where `rawreading` stands for what you just read from the potentiometer's input line.

```
potval = alpha*potval + (1-alpha)*rawreading;
```

Set `alpha` to a number (eg 0.8 or 0.9 or 0.95 etc) between 0 and 1.  `alpha` represents the fraction of the old value that you retain, and  `1-alpha` represents the fractional influence of the new raw reading.   `alpha` closer to 1 causes smoother but slower response.

If you prefer integer arithmetic for faster or smaller code, then represent `alpha` as a ratio of integers.  For example:

```
potval = (potval*12 + rawreading)/13;
```

The technique mentioned above is called *[exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#The_exponential_moving_average)* or  *exponential moving average*.

Answer (score 1):

Since the previous answers were all code-related, let me suggest you use a smoothing capacitor. In noisy environments, or where you want to get more consistent readings, place a capacitor across your signal lines (signal to ground). The result is less "spikes" in your readings, and can sometimes cause a slight delay in signal changes, as charge has to build up in the capacitor before the voltage goes up.

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-a-smoothing-capacitor

Comment: The circuit already uses 2 100microF capacitors. I forgot to specify.